# Wordpress MB Relationships fetch data

Tags: wordpress, meta-boxes

I'm using [MB Relationships](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mb-relationships/) plugin to create a relationship between two custom post types `movies` and `reviews`

Register relationship:

```
function register_movies_to_reviews_relationship()
{
    MB_Relationships_API::register([
        'id'   => 'movies_to_reviews',
        'from' => 'movies',
        'to'   => 'reviews',
    ]);
}

add_action('mb_relationships_init', 'register_movies_to_reviews_relationship');
```

=> It's working good

Fetch the reviews data by `movie_id`:

```
$reviews = MB_Relationships_API::get_connected([
   'id'   => 'movies_to_reviews',
   'from' => $movie_id
]);
```

=> It's working good

But i don't know how i can fetch the `movies` data by `review_id`.

How can i do that? Somebody can help me. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Shouldnt it be just replace from/to with the according id?

```
$reviews = MB_Relationships_API::get_connected([
'id'   => 'movies_to_reviews',
'to' => $review_id 
]);
```